# A data extraction - Need Ideas

Tags: parsing, data-mining, ontology, protege

---

Consider there are n rows of text similar to the ones below:

- "Sony KDL46NX720 BRAVIA 46" 3D LED Backlit HDTV - 1080p, 1920 x 1080, 16:9, 120Hz, HDMI, USB, WiFi Ready » for $1148.99  at Tiger Direct"
- "Samsung NV40 10.5 MP Digital Camera - Silver - 3x Zoom Lens » for $64.99  at eBay"
- "Gateway NV57H27u 15.6" Notebook, Intel Core i3-2310M (2.10GHz), 4GB DDR3 Memory, 500GB HDD, DVD Super Multi-Drive, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit (Pink) - LX.WZF02.002 » for $399.99  at Buy.com"

I would like to parse these strings and classify each of them as "TV, camera, laptop" etc.

The text attributes may or may not be similar.

---

How can this be comprehensively done?

What code/tools should I use?

What language?

I do not want to do a keyword search.
Can this strings be classified using class/attribute logic?

Can I use Protege to build the class/sub-class hierarchy?

---

I am totally new to this field of data-mining. So excuse my ignorance!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.ml-class.org/course/class/index  ;-)

Comment: You'll never get this going 100% reliably, since you're taking almost-freeform text and trying to extract meaning. What if someone has a Camera on sale but lists it as "XYZ Brand digital camera with bonus paper notebook to record exif data manually".

Comment: i also don't know a 100% solution. The only way i can think of is to have lists of keywords that classifies the category. e.g if the text contains the word "notebook" its a notebook and if it contains "LED Backlit" its a TV. OR you find a way to extract the model names (e.g. NV40) and search some shopping site for it and try to use their categories. but im really curious if someone here finds a good solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expresions, even a javascript can do the work

EDIT:

```
   var criteria = {
      camera : {
         identifier : /.*camera.*/ ,
         resolution : /.*(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d*).*/ ,
         value : /.*$(\d+).*/ ,
         ...
      },
      notebook : {
         identifier : /.*notebook.*/ ,
         ram : /.*(d+)GB\s*(DDR.).*/
         ...
      }
      ...
   }
```

Then write a simple engine that use this structure to analize each line

EDIT 2:

This is not easy at all because you heve to feed some sort of knowlege database, but is posible, you can feed this with pages like this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_power_dissipation

but is work for more than one person or for more than one day depending on how much intelligence you want for your code.

Comment: I doubt it. The poster wants to classify based on semantics, not just getting some parts of the text. This requires a much more sophisticated approach.

Comment: Okay, after your edit it does seem more feasible. Will still be a heuristic at best. But it would require manual verification.

Comment: I've got no other way. The closest I can come up with is an AI or neural network, like Raymond Hettinger pointed at.

Comment: Thanks all. @Delta Can you elaborate on the knowledge database idea? Limiting the code's focus on Electronics/Television only, can one build a simple ontology based knowledge database using protege (http://protege.stanford.edu/)?

Comment: In fact I was thinking of a python script to create some dictionary structure that holds arrays of regular expressions attached to some key to the dictionary, and then dump this to a file to create some sort of simple knowlege base, of corse this is a quick solution that needs a simple core (3 or 4 for loops) to analize the lines and dispatch classes that represent your items

Comment: This problem can be handled through "ONTOLOGY BASED TEXT MINING".  I am now using an open source tool called: [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/family/developer.html) I will post the solution soon.